# Connect to FTP via VPN

Tags: macos, vpn, ftp, filezilla, cyberduck

I work from home and need to connect to an ftp server. The ftp server has my work IP whitelisted and cannot connect from home. I set up a VPN, with Smart VPN (OSx) and made the connection to the office. Now I would like to connect to the ftp server, using my office IP address and I am not sure how to achieve that. I use Cyberduck or alternatively Filezilla as an ftp client.

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This [answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081660/connecting-to-ftp-via-vpn) seems to be what you are looking for:

> Open a CMD/Terminal and type "route print" or "netstat -r" take note
>   of where example.com is pointing to. Most likely the default route
>   will catch it. In that case you want to add a route to have it go via
>   the VPN interface for any traffic that goes to example.com (After
>   doing this, once you disconnect from the VPN you will not be able to
>   connect to example.com any more unless you connect to the VPN.)
>
> The other way is to connect to the FTP using the local IP of the FTP
>   once connected to the VPN.